# Button ng-click dont open new page defined on routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to open a view (html) by clicking in a button. This button will open a file declare in my route file.

I have my organizationView with a button when I click on it it opens a new page of configurations with 2 tasbs (organizationPermissionConfig.html). In this last page I have two tabs and in each tab I have a table where I can edit the properties of a row clicking on a button, but I don't know why this button isn't opening a new page.

app.routes.js

```
.state('app.organizationPermissionsSettings', {
          url: '/organization/permissionSettings/',
          templateUrl: 'app/components/organizations/organizationPermissionsConfig.html',
          resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                {
                  insertBefore: '#load_styles_before',
                  files: ['assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.min.css',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css']
                },
                { serie: true,
                  files: [
                    'assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.jquery.min.js',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
                    'assets/libs/bootstrap-datatables/bootstrap-datatables.js'                                      
                  ]}]).then(function () {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                      {
                        files: ['app/components/organizations/organizationsController.js',
                            'app/shared/layout/utils.js']
                      }
                    ])
                  });
            }]
          },
          data: {
            title: 'Settings',
          }
        })
.state('app.organization.graphs', {
          url: '/graphs',
          templateUrl: 'app/components/organizations/organizationGraphsView.html',
          resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                {
                  insertBefore: '#load_styles_before',
                  files: ['assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.min.css',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css']
                },
                { serie: true,
                  files: [
                    'assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.jquery.min.js',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
                    'assets/libs/bootstrap-datatables/bootstrap-datatables.js'

                  ]}]).then(function () {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                      {
                        files: ['app/components/organizations/organizationsController.js']
                      }
                    ])
                  });
            }]
          },
          data: {
            title: 'Organization Graphs',
          }
        })
        .state('app.organization.views', {
          url: '/views',
          templateUrl: 'app/components/organizations/organizationViewsView.html',
          resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                {
                  insertBefore: '#load_styles_before',
                  files: ['assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.min.css',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css']
                },
                { serie: true,
                  files: [
                    'assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.jquery.min.js',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
                    'assets/libs/bootstrap-datatables/bootstrap-datatables.js'

                  ]}]).then(function () {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                      {
                        files: ['app/components/organizations/organizationsController.js']
                      }
                    ])
                  });
            }]
          },
          data: {
            title: 'Organization Views',
          }
        })
```

organizationController.js

```
app.controller('OrganizationsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modal', 'HelperService', 'AuthService', '$state', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $modal, HelperService, AuthService, $state, $http) {
        var controllerScope = $scope;

        controllerScope.organizationsData = {};
        controllerScope.organizationsData.ajax = {url:'/api/organizations/', dataSrc:''};
        controllerScope.organizationsData.ajax.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", AuthService.authToken());
        }
        controllerScope.organizationsData.columns = [
            {"data":null,"render":function(data) {
                return '<a href="/#/organization/'+data.id+'">'+data.data.name+'</a>';
            }},
            {"data":"domain","defaultContent":""},
            {"data":null, "orderable":false, "render":function(data){
                return '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().openOrganizationPermissionsSettings(\''+data.id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>'
                +'<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px; " onclick=\'angular.element(this).scope().openNewOrganizationModal('+JSON.stringify(data)+')\'><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'
                +'<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().deleteOrganization(\''+data.id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
            }}];


        controllerScope.deleteOrganization = function (organizationId) {
            HelperService.deleteItem(organizationId, 'organization', '/api/organizations/');
        };

        controllerScope.openNewOrganizationModal = function (organization) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl : 'newOrganizationModalContent.html',
                controller: 'OrganizationsModalInstanceController',
                resolve: {organization:function () {return organization}},
            });
        }


        controllerScope.openOrganizationPermissionsSettings = function (organizationId) {
            $state.go('app.organizationPermissionsSettings');
        };


    }]);

app.controller('OrganizationsPermissionsSettingsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modal', 'HelperService', 'AuthService', '$state', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $modal, HelperService, AuthService, $state, $http) {
        var controllerScope = $scope;


        controllerScope.organizationGroups = [];

        $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups').success(function (data) {
            console.log("data ",data);
            controllerScope.organizationGroups = data;
        });

        controllerScope.openOrganizationPermissionsSettings = function (organizationId) {
            $state.go('app.organizationPermissionsSettings');
        };

    }]);


app.controller('OrganizationGraphsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'HelperService', '$http',        function ($rootScope, $scope, $modalInstance, HelperService, $http) {

            var controllerScope = $scope;

            controllerScope.organizationGroup = [];

            console.log("GraphsModalInstanceController organization "+$rootScope.organization.id);

            $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups/graphs/'+$rootScope.organization.id).success(function (data) {
                controllerScope.organizationGroup = data;
            });

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss();
            };
        }
    ]);

    app.controller('OrganizationViewsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'HelperService', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $modalInstance, HelperService, $http) {

            var controllerScope = $scope;

            controllerScope.organizationGroup = [];

            $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups/views/'+$rootScope.organization.id).success(function (data) {
                controllerScope.organizationGroup = data;
            });

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss();
            };

    }]);
```

organizationPermissionsConfig.html

```
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="app.organization.graphs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></td>

<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="app.organization.views"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is actually wrong:

```
ng-click="app.organization.graphs"
```

You need to inject the `$state` inside your controller, define a function inside your controller e.g. :

```
$scope.navigateToGraphs = function() {
    $state.go('app.organization.graphs');
}
```

And then bind the `ng-click` to this function:

```
ng-click="navigateToGraphs()"
```

Or you can also use plain html for doing that:

```
<a ui-sref="app.organization.graphs">Navigate to graphs</a>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I tried to do that inside OrganizationsPermissionsSettingsController and now I get "Error: Could not resolve 'app.organization.graphs' from state 'app.organizationPermissionsSettings'"

Comment: yeah this means that now your navigation is working :) Now the issue is inside your states definition. You are trying to access a state which is not reachable from the state you are currently in. It usually depends that you are on a state and the state your trying to get is not a direct child of the current state

Comment: I defined in my routes file "app.organizationPermissionsSettings" , "'app.organization.graphs" and "'app.organization.views" as you can see above. What I need to change?

Comment: This `app.organization.graphs` usually means that `graphs` is a child state of `organisations`.. do you really want that? otherwise changing simply `app.organization.graphs` to `app.organizationGraphs` should work directly because now `organizationPermissionsSettings` and `organizationGraphs` are both children of the `app` state. p.s. of course change then the code to use the new state: `app.organizationGraphs` instead of `app.organization.graphs`

Answer (score 0):

[`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) expects a method on the `$scope` to be called when you are clicking the button, but you are simply passing the state name to this directive which is not correct. So you have to implement a method that will use [`$state.go`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#examples-diagram) or you can use [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) directive like:

```
<td><a ui-sref="app.organization.graphs"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a></td>
```

Comment: I got the error "Error: Could not resolve 'app.organization.graphs' from state 'app.organizationPermissionsSettings'"